# I want UICollectionView grid that has no space on edge cells, only between cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using a `UICollectionViewController` to display a grid of photos, and would like to have no spacing on the outer boundary of the screen; only between the cells.

So the "edge" photos (far left, far right) would be right up against the respective edge of the screen, but there would be space between the cells.

I'm using the standard flow layout for this, implementing the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` and `insetForSectionAtIndex` methods. I'm hoping I don't have to do custom layouts..

How do I do this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What do you see now? As far as I know, that's the default behavior -- for instance if there's enough space for 2 cells across but not 3, then the two cells will be up against the left and right sides with whatever space between them that's necessary.

Comment: I see. So you're suggesting I don't implement `insetForSectionAtIndex` at all, which returns a `UIEdgeInsets` (which specifies padding in all 4 directions). I'll try this, thanks.